# express req.body can not get right json object?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to post json as follow to my node.js application:

```
{"zhinengList": [{"pos1": 1, "pos2": 2}] }
```

But `console.log(req.body)` get this:

```
{ zhinengList: [ 'pos2', 'pos1' ] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need to specify proper header in your request.

In case it's pure `XHR` request:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
```

with `jQuery`:

```
$.ajax({
  //..
  headers: {       
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
});
```

In this way server will parse it properly.